# Google console Tráfico de texto no cifrado permitido para todos los dominios

Tags: android, android-studio, aws

Chicos tengo un problema al subir mi apk al google play, me esta arrojando un error de seguridad que dice "Tráfico de texto no cifrado permitido para todos los dominios", allí mismo dicen como podría solucionar con unos ejemplos, implemento eso en mi archivo de configuración de red pero me genera una excepción al momento de consumir esa url, el servicio se encuentra almacenado en amazon

Codigo

```
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">URL</domain>
    <certificates src="system" />
</domain-config>
```

Este es otra forma

```
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">URL</domain>
    <certificates src="system" />
</domain-config>
```

De ambas formas me genera el mismo error al tratar de consumir la url
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe por que pasa esto y como solucionar??

Answer (score 0):

A partir de Android 9 (API nivel 28), la compatibilidad "ClearText" está deshabilitada de forma predeterminada.

Ya que esta deshabilitada (`cleartextTrafficPermitted="false"` ), debes habilitarla para poder realiza peticiones a urls no cifradas http://, cambia a:

```
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
```

pero lo ideal es que asegures que tu aplicacion use unicamente urls cifradas `https://`